# Unity Vuforia AR: Using Vuforia's Model Target (Guide View) to detect real objects and render the 3D objects (created in Unity3D) on the real objects

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia, hololens

I am working on a project using **Vuforia's Model Target (Guide View Mode)** and Unity3D for **HoloLens 2**. When I detect a real object, I can successfully display 3D objects created in Unity3D (which include empty objects with Line Renderer components). However, I have one issue: when I move the HoloLens 2 on my head, the empty objects with the Line Renderer component applied move along with my head's rotation or movement.

The project I want to create is related to an experiment with Convex Lens.[image: just like this] In simple terms, I use Model Target to detect a real object (the light source of the experimental apparatus) and display the path of light. For the light path, I use empty objects with Line Renderer components. When I move the light source, the light path changes accordingly. I have a method to ensure that when I move the light source, the starting point of the light path also moves with it. This method involves writing a script (the script is provided below) that sets the maximum number of endpoints(line.positionCount) for the Line Renderer component, its start and end points (public), and then, in the Update method, I set the positions of each endpoint. Finally, in the Inspector, I specify the objects to connect as the starting and ending points for the objects with the applied script. [image: here is the image of Inspector]

```
// here is the Script
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class LineControl : MonoBehaviour
{
    public LineRenderer line;
    public Transform startPoint;
    public Transform endPoint;

    void Start()
    {
        line.positionCount = 2;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        line.SetPosition(0, startPoint.position);
        line.SetPosition(1, endPoint.position);
    }
}
```

In my project, the light path is essentially an extension of this method, and it mostly works well. However, as mentioned earlier, there is an issue where the starting points of all three lines (in total) are connected to the real object I want to detect, the light source of the experimental apparatus. When I move or rotate my head, the starting point of these lines moves or rotates with my head (even though I am not moving the light source), which subsequently alters the calculated results, leading to incorrect results (the calculations of those lines are correct). Other objects in the scene do not exhibit this behavior.

Version:
Unity: 2022.3.10f1 LTS,
Vuforia Engine: 10.17.4

This is the video I recorded [(video link)](https://youtu.be/6MQ41pvhsmw), in the video, you can see that when I move my head, the starting point of the light on the light source also moves accordingly. So, every time I want to see where the intersection point is, it moves with my head as I turn.

Is this normal in Vuforia Model Target?
How can I solve this problem?

I don't know where the problem is, so I'm unsure where to begin troubleshooting.

My expectation is that the lines should only move when I'm moving the light source in the experimental apparatus. When I move or rotate the HoloLens 2 on my head, the start point of those three lines should remain fixed at the light source's location.[image: here is the image that I test on HoloLens 2]

Comment: I am not sure I understand the problem well but in Hololens everything you want to render must placed in Hololens 3D world. Then the rendering is fully managed by Hololens itself. This is different from rendering on mobile devices where you can have both 3D and 2D rendering elements.